# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index' in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I want to create the index of one dataframe equal to the index of another dataframe.

```
y_test_proba.index = X_test.index
```

But it has an error.

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
```

**How to solve this error?**

Comment: Either `y_test_proba` or `X_test` or both are not a DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coercing the array to a Pandas DataFrame will give you access to indices.

```
X_test_df = pandas.DataFrame(X_test)
X_test_df.index
```